# How can I register a anonymous user with Django and tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

```
class CreateUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        object_class = User
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        include_resource_uri = False
        fields = ['username']
        models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        username, password = bundle.data['username'], bundle.data['password']
        #try:
        bundle.obj = User.objects.create_user(username, '', password)
        #except IntegrityError:
            #raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
        #return bundle
```

I am using this resource to create new user. But in order to do this, I need an api_key. Since I am anonymous, how can I get api_key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create an user without being authenticated/authorized?

```
authentication = Authentication()
authorization = Authorization()
```

ApiKeyAuthentication() needs an appr. entry in db table 'tastypie_apikey'...

This is how I create an user account while being unauthenticated:

```
class CreateUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'user'
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        object_class = User
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        include_resource_uri = False
        fields = ['username']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            bundle = super(CreateUserResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
            bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
            bundle.obj.save() 
            '''assign user to a group w/ sufficient permissions''' 
            user = User.objects.get(id=bundle.obj.id)
            group = Group.objects.get(id=1)
            user.groups.add(group)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
        return bundle
```

Comment: Ok. I edited my code. Now I have another question: After successful creation of new user, with which api_key will new user make request?

Comment: At first: `user = User.objects.get(id=bundle.obj.id)` is somewhat creepy, `bundle.obj.groups.add(group)` should be fine...

Well, at first you should check if the `models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)` works by checking the table tastypie_apikey...

Fetching the key is fairly simple right after user creation:
`apikey = ApiKey.objects.get(user=bundle.obj)`